# Pointer value as an argument

Tags: c

The value in the `printf` hasn't changed after applying the void function `f`, which is confusing me. It's basic stuff revolving pointers. The exact question is: *Why isn't the end value 2 instead of 1?*

```
int a=1, b=2;

void f(int* p) {
    p=&b;
}

int main() { 
    int *p=&a;
    f(p);
    printf("%d\n", *p);
}
```

The `*p` value in main remains 1, and that's what's confusing me.

Comment: Because `f()` does nothing of any effect. It alters the copy of the argument it was given, does nothing with it, and discards it.

Comment: Edit: uh hold on, I think I got it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to dereference `p` and remove the `&` address operator from `b`

This assigns the value of `b` to the address where `p` points to:

```
void f(int* p) 
{
    *p = b;
}
```

The reson why it printed `1` and not e.g. the address of `b` is that you assigned: `p = &b` which just assigns the address of `b` to the local pointer variable `p`. This means it **does not** point to `a` anymore here. But since this was just a local copy it didn't change the value of the `p` you passed in `main()`.

This makes it a little more obvious:

```
void f(int* ptr) 
{
    // assign a value
    *ptr = 1337;
}

int main() 
{ 
    int local_integer = 666;

    // prints "666"
    printf("%d\n", local_integer);

    f(&local_integer);

    // prints "1337"
    printf("%d\n", local_integer);
}
```

Comment: You will need to ditch the ampersand for this to even compile. Edit : there it goes :p

Comment: Yep sorry, oversaw that that.

Comment: Nice, that example cleared thing up quite a bit, forgot that it was a local copy and that transmission is done by value

Answer (score 0):

In your code you define a pointer to int on the stack. Its value is the same as the pointer in the `main()` function which happens to point to the ąddress of the variable `a`. Then you change its value (so the pointer on the stack now points to `b`) then you just drop that pointer.

```
void f(int* p) {
    p=&b;
}
```

That is why if you dereference the pointer in `main` it still points to the address of the int variable `a`.